# Getting an invalid_scope for youtube.upload device code request

Tags: youtube-api

I am trying to use the Youtube data API from an app, and I'd like to just request permission to upload videos, not to manage their entire Youtube account.

When I try to request an access token for the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload, I get back an error saying it is an invalid scope. I've given the app permission to the Youtube v3 data API.

According to the v3 youtube docs, these are the supported scopes:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube - Manage your YouTube account.
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly - View your YouTube account.
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload - Upload YouTube videos and manage your YouTube videos.

The only one of these 3 that works for me is "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube".

This is the request I am attempting:

```
curl -d "client_id=id&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload" https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code
```

And this is the response:

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_scope",
  "error_description" : "Not authorized to request the scopes: [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload]",
  "error_uri" : "http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html"
}
```

I am thinking that maybe this type of request just doesn't work for device codes? The youtube.upload scope request seems to work fine in the oauth2 playground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: This issue has been fixed.

This scope by itself was not whitelisted for the devices. Filed a request internally.

On the other hand, as [explained here](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/09/the-youtube-api-on-stack-overflow.html), Stackoverflow is for programming questions, you can use public issue tracker for bug reports or feature requests.

Feel free to [file a bug report in issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20%28Defect%20Report%29) to get updated on this issue.

Comment: Thanks! I will file this as an issue - I wasn't sure if I was just doing something wrong.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm getting the same error when using the youtube.force-ssl scope, but as it is apparently identical in actual behaviour to the youtube scope, I guess it's easier just to switch to that (despite force-ssl being preferred according to the documentation).  Thanks.